# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost and log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["requestid"]

Tags: c#, log4net, asp.net-core-2.0, web-hosting, threadcontext

I use netcore2.0 and I'm setting log4net.LogicalThreadContext property "requestid" with each request in my middleware class for logging purposes.

```
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["requestid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

But "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost" class does not show this property when logging rows.

I do not know how to set log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Propery["requestid"] for "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost".

I wish to tie all request logs from the beginning to the end.
Does anyone have any insights which might help?

Regards!

UPDATE: Here is the code

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
...

public static ILoggerProvider Log4NetProvider;

public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

#if DEBUG
        Log4NetProvider = new Log4NetProvider("log4net.Debug.config", ((o, 
exception) => exception.Message));
#else
        Log4NetProvider = new Log4NetProvider("log4net.Release.config", ((o, 
exception) => exception.Message));
#endif
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())                
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddProvider(Log4NetProvider);                   
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddAutofac();
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
        host.Run();
```

In Startup.cs 
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) i've set up as the very first thing.

`app.UseMiddleware<Log4NetRequestIdMiddleware>();`

```
public class Log4NetRequestIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public Log4NetRequestIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["requestid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Log4net config file>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\log\applog.log" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="500"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%utcdate|%-5level|%logger|%property{requestid}| %message %exception%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Additional example from Fileappender.log (bold marking the RequestId)

> 2018-04-10 14:02:28,664|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|**(null)**| Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost...
>   2018-04-10 14:02:28,956|INFO| Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker|**cfb2709e3b4f40559c365ecbb08a7746**| Executing action method Controllers.HealtCheckStatusController.GetHealthCheckStatus 
>   2018-04-10 14:02:29,486|INFO| Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor|**cfb2709e3b4f40559c365ecbb08a7746**| Executing ObjectResult, writing value Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext.
>   2018-04-10 14:02:29,510|INFO| Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker|**cfb2709e3b4f40559c365ecbb08a7746**| Executed action Controllers.HealtCheckStatusController.GetHealthCheckStatus in 564.464ms
>   2018-04-10 14:02:29,520|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|**(null)**| Request finished in 858.9575ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: Post your code please. I just tried your scenario using the first middleware of my pipeline and it works.

Comment: Still couldn't reproduce. To except any unclearness post your `log4net config` and `Log4NetProvider`.

Comment: Hei, sorry for the delay. Posted log4net config and example where it does not show the "requestId"

Comment: There's no more code for Log4NetProvider. It's a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging ILoggerProvider implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why `WebHost` logger does not show the property

`WebHost` logger logs two messages - Request starting message and Request finished message.

Request starting message doesn't see `requestid` property because `WebHost` runs and logs the message before the first middleware included into pipeline in `Startup` class where `requestid` property is set.

Request finished message doesn't see `requestid` property because (I guess) `WebHost` logger is out of `log4net.LogicalThreadContext`. It is like `Log4NetRequestIdMiddleware` logger would not see `requestid` property if it would be set in controller action.

#### Possible solution

Since `WebHost` logger logs messages somewhere deep in [`HostingApplicationDiagnostics`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/f9d145887773e0c650e66165e0c61886153bcc0b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingApplicationDiagnostics.cs) class from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal` namespace there is no any clear extension points to inject the code that would set `requestid` property.
So, I think you can just log info in your middleware like it does `WebHost` logger:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var logger = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Log4NetRequestIdMiddleware>>();
    log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["requestid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    
    var request = context.Request;
    string logMsg = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "Request starting {0} {1} {2}://{3}{4}{5}{6} {7} {8}",
            request.Protocol,
            request.Method,
            request.Scheme,
            request.Host.Value,
            request.PathBase.Value,
            request.Path.Value,
            request.QueryString.Value,
            request.ContentType,
            request.ContentLength);
    
    logger.LogDebug(logMsg);

    await _next(context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Albert for looking into this. I guess this is the only way then and I'll use it. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can look this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging-providers

## Create your own LogProvider, clear log provider like this.

```
            services.AddLogging(config =>
            {
                config.ClearProviders();
            });

            loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
```

This article tells how to create a log4net Logger.
https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-log4net-with-aspnetcore-for-logging/